# tunnel two windows or linux server with routing packets

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, routing, tunneling

I would like to use IPIP eoip tunnel for windows/linux. In addition, It's not necessary to be IPIP, I want to route connection from server 1 to server 2.

You can see following flowchart: 
http://i44.tinypic.com/vr4vwh.jpg

Flow chart description: employees use pptp/l2tp connection to connect server 1 (office1). then server 1(office 1) route the data to server 2 thru an IPIP or eoip tunnel or something like this via interAnet. server 2 is connected to a broadband internet that would let my employees connects to internet.

Comment: Xpost - http://superuser.com/questions/601392/how-to-tunnel-two-linux-server

Comment: @Zoredache nobody has answered the link that you have. I'm looking for answer